# Name for a alternative version of the image of a functor

Tags: category-theory, terminology, functors

I'm wondering if there is an established terminology for the following variation on the notion of image. Given a functor $F : C \to D$, one can define the following category:

- the objects are those of $C$,
- the morphisms from $c$ to $c'$ are the morphisms from $f: F(c) \to F(c')$ in $D$ such that there exists $g:c\to c'$ in $C$ satisfying $F(g)=f$,
- the identities and compositions are inherited from $D$.

Is there a name for this category? (If $F$ is full, we recover the [full image](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+image) of $F$.)
This category, let us call it $\mathfrak{im}(F)$ in this post, comes with a factorization of $F$ as
$$
C \overset p \to \mathfrak {im}(F) \overset i \to D
$$
where $p$ is full (and bijective on objects) and $i$ is faithful. However, I'm not sure this factorization is universal in any sense.

Comment: @varkor Thanks, the fact it is the full image of the image can be useful. I am aware the essential image is usually much better behaved, categorically speaking, but in my case I really want to avoid "generation of new morphism".

Comment: @varkor Actually, writing my previous comment, I come to doubt your statement: take the functor $\Delta^1 \to \mathsf{Set}$ sending both object to $\mathbb N$ and the unique non identity arrow to the successor function $s$. Then the full image of the image functor will contain $s^n$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$ (if my quick mental computation is correct, this full image will be equivalent to the delooping of the monoid $\mathbb N$). While my construction will actually be isomorphic to $\Delta^1$ I think.

Comment: @varkor This is what I meant, sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the post right away.

Comment: So your construction is essentially identifying any two morphisms $f$ and $g$ in $C$ whose image under $F$ is the same. This is indeed not the same as what I wrote before; I'll remove that comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: I really don't understand the definition on the nlab of the "essential image" of a functor. Surely we don't want to say that the image of the functor $Δ^1 → \mathbf{Set}$ sending the unique non-isomorphism to the identity $ℕ→ℕ$ is different from the image of any other functor sending this unique non-isomorphism to any bijection $X→Y$ between countable sets.

Comment: Or are we speaking about strict categories? What did I miss? Even after taking the replete closures, I can't make sense of this construction in the context of non-strict categories. For instance, the first possibility would give the category of all identities of countable sets while the second one would give the connected groupoid of all the bijections between finite sets.

Comment: They speak about violating some principle of equivalence, but the essential image as defined on the nlab violates the principle that two isomorphic functors should have equivalent images. They say that the replete completion of the image need not be equivalent to the image, but this is because of that. I'm tired so did I completely miss something?

Comment: The only definition of "image of a functor" that makes sense according to me is your construction as presented above, so I believe you should just call it the image of the functor (essential or not, I don't get the point of such distinctions in this context if we don't care about equality of objects).

Comment: Ooops, I wrote "bijections between finite sets" above instead of "bijections between *countable* sets".

Comment: @Idéophage If you take the essential image (in the sense of nLab) of the constant functor $\Delta^1 \to \mathsf{Set}$ at $\mathbb N$, then any iso $f:X\to Y$ between countable sets is int it. Indeed, the arrow $f$ is isomorphic in $\mathrm{Arr}(\mathsf{Set})$ to $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb N}$ as follows: take any iso $\phi: \mathbb N \to X$, then the pair $(\phi, f\circ \phi)$ is a isomorphism from $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb N}$ to $f$. Does this help?

Comment: @Idéophage Notice that in my case, I try to avoid $D$-composable chains that are not the image of $C$-composable chains. Hence my alternate definition.

Comment: Yes, it helps, thank you. You are right, any isomorphism between countable sets is in the essential image of the constant functor at $ℕ$. So this notion is invariant by equivalence, ok. But I still find this definition quite strange. For instance, the "essential image" of the terminal category in any groupoid is the whole groupoid. I believe what you describe is what should be called the "image" if we want something that is invariant by equivalences, right?

Comment: (connected groupoid, I meant)

Comment: @Idéophage Yes, the essential image of the terminal category in a connected groupoid is the groupoid itself. I'm not sure what you mean by "invariant by equivalences", could you precise what you have in mind?

Comment: Let $F : A→B$ and $G : X→Y$ be two functors. They are equivalent if there is some equivalence $A≅X$ and $B≅Y$ making the square commute up to natural isomorphism. Then the "images" of $F$ and $G$ should be equivalent categories. I don't know what to impose more but it is not even enough (a priori), because if we just say that, it could be some strange convoluted equivalence that we just prove to exist with no explicit characterization in a 50 pages proof. We really want something very natural, for instance given by a universal property.

Comment: And in your example, there is a universal property, even if probably not what you asked for when you mentioned universality. The image represents the 2-presheaf sending a category $A$ to the category of functors $G:C→A$ such that $G(f) = G(h)$ as soon as $F(f) = F(h)$ for any pair of parallel arrows $f$ and $h$. I don't know 2-category theory but it looks like some coequalizer of some kernel pair, and I think it's the most natural notion of "image" of a functor.

Comment: @Idéophage I think you're right my definition is equivalent to some kind of 2-colimit in CAT. But I'm still puzzled about your initial objection to essential image: given two equivalent functors in the sense you wrote, how can the essential images be non-equivalent? Is there an obvious counter-example I don't see? (By the way, the essential image also has a universal property of some sort, namely the factorization through the essential image is initial (maybe 2-initial rather) among the factorization trough an isofibration injective on objects and morphisms.)

Comment: Actually I was wrong: I agree that this definition is invariant by equivalence.